# What is a node id in facebook graph api and how can I find it?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Hello and thank you in advance, I'm currently looking through the documentation for facebook graph api and I am trying to understand it.

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
"/{photo-id}",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

The graph api has a convention of using the id(as seen above) of the node you want to get data from. I'm not sure where to get the id for each of the nodes. If someone could explain it or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thank you again.

Comment: You want your own images or your friends?

Comment: You get the ID by calling other APIs. `/me` for example returns the ID of the current user. `/me/photos` return a bunch of IDs of photos.

Comment: @PHPglue  well  I want the users after the use the facebook login on my application

Comment: @WizKid thank you, would you also happen to know how to get the image url from the id by any chance ?

Comment: You just call `/{id}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Facebook example to get your pictures:

```js
// myapp.js
function fbAsyncInit(){
  FB.init({
    appId: 'your-app-id',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
    if(r.status === 'connected'){
      // all the magic must happen here
      FB.api('me/photos?type=uploaded', function(u){
        var d = u.data; // array of photo info
        for(var i=0,l=d.length; i<l; i++){
          // individual photo data
          FB.api(d[i].id, function(p){
            // p is photo
          });
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=yourClientIdHere&redirect_uri=yourWebPageToRedirectToWhenLoggedIn';
    }
  });
  // remove comments to see errors
  //FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
}
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='myapp.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    Nothing to See But the JavaScript and HTML &lt;script&gt; tag order
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```